# Pillow Image can't release memory when it closes

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using `Pillow==4.2.0` like following by Python3.
I just want to release the memory after used Image.

```
from PIL import Image

f = open('http://test.com/test.jpg', 'rb')
image = Image.open(f)
image.load() # use a lot of memories

f.close()
image.close() # this doesn't release memory

f = None
image = None
```

Also I tried to use `gc.collect()`. But it wasn't efficient.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: `del image` / `image = None` ?

Comment: @asongtoruin I tried those. but not efficient.

Comment: How did you measure memory consumption?

Comment: @physicalattraction I just used `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss`