# Memory not freed upon image.close() in Pillow

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am struggling to de-allocate from a Pillow Image.

If I run the following:

```
@profile
def do_image_things():
  im = Image.open(foo.png')
  im.close()
  del im
```

Then I get the following output from Python's memory_profiler:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     8   33.645 MiB   33.645 MiB   @profile
     9                             def do_image_things():
    12   37.383 MiB    3.738 MiB     im = Image.open(u'foo.png')
    13   37.387 MiB    0.004 MiB     im.close()
    14   37.387 MiB    0.000 MiB     del im
```

The `im.close()` call appears not to have de-allocated the memory that the `Image.open()` reserved. The is a bare-bones reproduction of an issue occurring in a large-scale image processing deployment that we've noticed memory problems in.

Has anyone been able to resolve this problem?

I'm running Pillow Version 5.0.0 and 2.7.14 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Interesting... this refers https://stackoverflow.com/q/44882598/2836621

Comment: Same results with Python 3.7.1 and PIL 5.2.0 on macOS Mojave.